# How to match value types to keys when using index signatures in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, index-signature

I have a code in a library for doing some kind of eventsourcing.
It defines events with a given type and data for each kind of events.

I want to write a reduce function that walks through a list of events and apply them to a given initial value.

My question is how I can define the type of the reducer function `eventData` parameter to match the current key? My goal is to get TypeScript to infer parameter types based on the object key so I don't have to typecast the event data parameters (i.e.: `(eventData as AddEvent['data'])`).

In a nutshell: currently the `wrongReducer` object leads to TypeScript errors but I want to define the `Reducer` type to make it work this way.

Is there any TypeScript magic to achieve this?

```js
// Library code:

export interface Event<
    Type extends string = string,
    Data extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>
> {
    type: Type
    data: Data
}

type Reducer<T, E extends Event> = {
    [k in E['type']]: (current: T, eventData: E['data']) => T
    // What to write instead of E['data']?
}

// Example code:

type AddEvent = Event<'add', { addend: number }>
type SubstractEvent = Event<'substract', { subtrahend: number }>
type MultiplyEvent = Event<'multiply', { multiplicant: number }>

type OperatorEvent = AddEvent | SubstractEvent | MultiplyEvent

const reducer: Reducer<number, OperatorEvent> = {
    add: (current, eventData) => current + (eventData as AddEvent['data']).addend,
    substract: (current, eventData) => current - (eventData as SubstractEvent['data']).subtrahend,
    multiply: (current, eventData) => current * (eventData as MultiplyEvent['data']).multiplicant
}

/*
const wrongReducer: Reducer<number, OperatorEvent> = {
    add: (current, eventData) => current + eventData.addend,
    substract: (current, eventData) => current - eventData.subtrahend,
    multiply: (current, eventData) => current * eventData.multiplicant
}
// TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
// test/so.ts:32:54 - error TS2339: Property 'addend' does not exist on type '{ addend: number; } | { subtrahend: number; } | { multiplicant: number; }'.
//   Property 'addend' does not exist on type '{ subtrahend: number; }'.

// 32     add: (current, eventData) => current + eventData.addend,
//                                                         ~~~~~~
// test/so.ts:33:60 - error TS2339: Property 'subtrahend' does not exist on type '{ addend: number; } | { subtrahend: number; } | { multiplicant: number; }'.
//   Property 'subtrahend' does not exist on type '{ addend: number; }'.

// 33     substract: (current, eventData) => current - eventData.subtrahend,
//                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~
// test/so.ts:34:59 - error TS2339: Property 'multiplicant' does not exist on type '{ addend: number; } | { subtrahend: number; } | { multiplicant: number; }'.
//   Property 'multiplicant' does not exist on type '{ addend: number; }'.

// 34     multiply: (current, eventData) => current * eventData.multiplicant
//                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
*/

const events: OperatorEvent[] = [
    { type: 'add', data: { addend: 2 } },
    { type: 'multiply', data: { multiplicant: 5 } },
    { type: 'add', data: { addend: 3 } },
    { type: 'substract', data: { subtrahend: 4 } }
]

let val = 0

for (const event of events) {
    val = reducer[event.type](val, event.data)
}

console.log(`Result: ${val}`)
// Result: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work using a bit of a creative version of [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```js
type Reducer<T, E extends Event> = {
    [event in E as event['type']]: (current: T, eventData: event['data']) => T;
}
```

Basically `event` refers to whatever `E` can be, which for `Reducer<any, OperatorEvent>` is `AddEvent`, `SubstractEvent` or `MultiplyEvent`.

The `eventData` parameter in your `reducer`/`wrongReducer`'s fields are properly typed based on the field name. E.g. `eventData` for `add` is of type:

[image]

---

In a more classic fashion, `OperatorEvent` would usually be replaced with an "event map" or similar, which is a lot easier and more straight-forward to map types over.